# zoom-available not present on load

Tags: magento-1.9, zoom

The default 1.9 product magnifier is not initialising properly on page load. But does initialise when a thumbnail i.e. `.thumb-link` is clicked.

I have done a diff on the difference between `.product-image` and it's descendants before and after manual initialisation of the magnifier by virtue of clicking on a thumbnail.

The difference is the addition of `zoom-available` to the `product-image` class as well as `visible` to the `gallery-image` class.

Answer (score 2):

That class is added to the element depending upon the dimensions of product image. Check the dimensions of both images, one that can't magnify and one that can. You'll be able to see the difference easily.

I remember seeing this hardcoded in somewhere in a JS file, my first guess would be app.js as that does most of the heavy job in that Magento version. You can update that per your requirements.

Just remember to make it big enough so that you don't actually end up serving zoom for very small files. After all that's why it was applied in first place.

Comment: In my scenario the images were and are zoomable, and zoom-available if I clicked on the thumbnail first. It is again not an issue for some strange reason. *Not cache related*. If it happens again I will bear these suggestions in mind though~